# Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted sof

Tags: flutter, dart

before 2 days the dart updated and the following error show its can not build any app even new one

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.

Command: D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/90fa3ae28fe6ddaee1af2c120f01e50201c1401b/ -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages "D:\flutter projects\baldya_app.dart_tool\package_config.json" --output-dill "D:\flutter projects\baldya_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\44174555a708b887b6be6743d2b71e3d\app.dill" --depfile "D:\flutter projects\baldya_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\44174555a708b887b6be6743d2b71e3d\kernel_snapshot.d" --incremental --initialize-from-dill "D:\flutter projects\baldya_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\44174555a708b887b6be6743d2b71e3d\app.dill" --source file:///D:/flutter%20projects/baldya_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --source package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart -Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///D:/flutter%20projects/baldya_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --verbosity=error package:baldya_app/main.dart
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIgZh.jpg)

I downgrade flutter and updated it download the last version and the same[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99CMa.jpg)